# ThreeJS: Is there any possible way to reduce the amount of triangles count

Tags: three.js

Hi I have some very complex models to display which comes from Revit files that my customer provides.

But sometimes the amount of details in the model is just way too much for the purpose of the website.

I would like to reduce the amount of vertexes/triangles in the model to simplify the display and enhance performance.

I have used simply modifiers where I cant able to view the model itself.

Is this possible from within ThreeJS? Or is there maybe an other solution for this?

```
  const renderMeshFunction = async (material: any, geometry: any, id: any) => {

        let count = 0;

        const emptyFunction = () => { };


        const onBR = () => {
            const _count = (count < 3 ? count : Math.floor(Math.random() * count) + 1);
            return ((renderer: WebGLRenderer, scene: Scene,
                camera: Camera, geometry: Geometry | BufferGeometry,
                _material: Material, group: Group) => {

                _material.clippingPlanes = checkIsClipping();
            });
        };

        count = geometry.maxInstancedCount;
        const mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);

        let modifier = new SimplifyModifier();
        let simplified = mesh.clone();

        simplified.material = simplified.material.clone();
        let countSimple = Math.floor((simplified.geometry as any).attributes.position.count * 1); // number of vertices to remove
        simplified.geometry = modifier.modify(simplified.geometry, countSimple);
        that.scene.add(simplified);

        mesh.name = id || Date.now().toString();
        mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
        mesh.drawMode = 0;

        mesh.onBeforeRender = onBR.apply(that);
        mesh.onAfterRender = emptyFn;


        mesh.geometry.dispose();
        mesh.material.dispose();
        geometry.dispose();
        material.dispose();
        material = undefined;

        return mesh;
    };
```

Comment: Have you already checked this demo? https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_simplifier.

Comment: Yes! I do @Mugen87 I have used simply modifiers where I cant able to view the model itself.

Comment: Well, this is the only way to reduce the complexity of geometries in `three.js` right now.

Comment: You can avoid using an animation loop: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_matcap.html